# how to use indexOf to determine if a certain set of characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, indexof

let's say I have an array of 30 strings.

I want to determine if the string contains let's say characters of "ea" and I will then alert the strings that contains ea.

I want to use indexOf how can I do that?

let's say if I have an array of

var new = ["banana","apple","orange"];

I tried something like...

```
new_an = new.indexOf("an");
for (i=0; i < new.length;i++ )
{

if (new_an = -1)
{
    alert(new[i]);
}
}
```

so only banana and orange has an in it and I I only want to alert those two....but not sure what am I missing here...

Comment: please provide, your array example !

Comment: `I want to determine if the string` which is **the** string? You have an array of 30 strings right?

Comment: Matei Mihai has posted the correct answer. Besides that @new@ is a reserved keyword and hence not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 1):

[indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) is returning -1 if there is no match in given string. You can do like this:

```
var arr = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "test"];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].indexOf('str') != -1) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

The output of this example should be: string 1, string 2, string 3

Answer (score 0):

Use following solution in loop over the array of string.

```
Example

Search a string for "welcome":

var str="Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n=str.indexOf("welcome");
The result of n will be:

13
```

[See here for more details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply loop through the array and then check with `String.contains()` whether your search string is in the original string.

```
str.contains(searchString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
    for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
        if (strArray[j].match(str)) return j;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

j is index of str in array.

Answer (score 0):

One way using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter);

```
var it   = ["aea", "b", "c", "dea", "eee", "fea"];
var find = "ea";

var matches = it.filter(function(el) {
  return el.indexOf(find) > -1;
});

alert(matches);
```